# flask_jwt_extended CSRF_Token in flask_restful

Tags: python, access-token, flask-restful, csrf-token, flask-jwt-extended

I'm only setting access token in cookies. But I found CSRF_token also in cookies. I don't understand why it's happening and how it's happening.

Look my code:-
**Setting access token.**

```py
     access_token = create_access_token(identity=user.id, fresh=True)
     refresh_token = create_refresh_token(identity=user.id)
     resp=Response.SUCCESS(data={'id': user.id, 'refresh_token': refresh_token})
     set_access_cookies(resp,access_token)
     return resp
```

**cookies**

[image: Postman Cookies]

When I am using `@jwt_requiured((locations=['cookies'],fresh=True)`  it returning **Missing CSRF token**.
Here, I need to pass CSRF token through header. Does anyone know what is happening here ? and What should I do ?

Comment: Hello @FasilK check the doc. to set csrf-token https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/token_locations/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out that, flask_jwt_extended CSRF_Token work like this. As a solution for that either disable csrf protection (`app.config["JWT_COOKIE_CSRF_PROTECT"] = False`) or pass csrf_token through header.